# Cov(y,z)? when z=min(Y)

Tags: covariance, extreme-value

For independently distributed normal random variables $y_i$ ~ $N(\mu_i, \sigma_i ^2 )$

Let $z =$ min$(Y) $, where $Y=${$y_1,y_2,y_3...y_n$}.

How to calculate cov$(y_j,z)$ ?

I tried to calculate it as

Let $z_{e,i} =$ min$(Y_{e,i}) $ where $Y_{e,i}$ is defined that $y_i$ is excluded from $Y$.
So that,

$z =$ min$(Y_{e,i},y_i) $ = min$(Y)$

and,

cov$(y_i,z)$ =cov$(y_i,$min$(Y_{e,i},y_i)$)

If i assume  cov$(Y_{e,i},y_i)=0$ ,it is possible to calculate cov$(y_i,z)$. (I know the equation to solve cov($y_i$,min$(y_i,y_j))$ if i know the cov$(y_i,y_j)$)

However when i calculated the expected minimum according to,
$$ E(z_1)=E(min(y_1,y_2))$$
$$=\mu_1\varphi(a)+ \mu_2\varphi(-a) + \sqrt{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2}\phi(a)$$
where a is
$$ (\mu_1-\mu_2)/\sqrt{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2}$$

and chain it for more than two , the different calculation order makes different results such as
$$ E[min(min(y_1,y_2),y_3)] \neq E[min(min(y_3,y_2),y_1)] $$

so that it also probably,
$$  E[min(Y_{e,i},y_i)]  \neq E[min(Y)]$$

if i follow the above calculation way to calculate the expected value.

Are there better idea to calculate cov$(y_j,z)$?